# Autocad C# delete layout viewports

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

Can anyone help me to create a C# code to delete the viewport in layouts.

I've tried a code to delete the viewport, it compiles no problem, but it doesn't delete the viewport, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

```
public class Class1
{
    [CommandMethod("haha")]
    
    public static void CreateModelViewports()
    {
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        using (Transaction trans = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            var viewportTable = (ViewportTable)trans.GetObject(db.ViewportTableId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
            foreach (ObjectId id in viewportTable)
            {
                var viewport = (ViewportTableRecord)trans.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
                // Delete the active viewport
               
                    viewport.UpgradeOpen();
                    viewport.Erase();
                
            }
                           
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you at least try something? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am new to C# for autocad,  just trying to grab a code that can delete the viewport. I don't even know how to get it started. Here's what I have.

Comment: You're going to need to step through your code in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You are erasing a `ViewportTableRecord` not a `Viewport`.

You need to get `BlockTableRecordId` from the Layout you want to erase its viewports. Then iterate through every `ObjectId` in that `BlockTableRecord` to see if it is a `Viewport`. Only then you can delete them

So if you want to delete all Viewports in the current layout you do something like this (You must be in paper space for this to work, because it doesn't check)

```
[CommandMethod("GOO")]
    public static void test()
    {
        Database DB = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Database;
        using (Transaction trans = DB.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            LayoutManager LM = LayoutManager.Current;
            string currentLo = LM.CurrentLayout;
            DBDictionary LayoutDict = trans.GetObject(DB.LayoutDictionaryId, OpenMode.ForRead) as DBDictionary;
            Layout CurrentLo = trans.GetObject((ObjectId)LayoutDict[currentLo], OpenMode.ForRead) as Layout;
            BlockTableRecord BlkTblRec = trans.GetObject(CurrentLo.BlockTableRecordId, OpenMode.ForRead) as BlockTableRecord;
            foreach (ObjectId ID in BlkTblRec)
            {
                Viewport VP = trans.GetObject(ID, OpenMode.ForRead) as Viewport;
                if (VP != null)
                {
                    VP.UpgradeOpen();
                    VP.Erase();
                }
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey Mavios, thank you so much for pointing out what I did wrong and I did try with your code but I get a Fatal Error and it just crushes the autocad. I'll try to play with the block table record id see if I get any luck.

Comment: @IStop I edited the code to make it work on current layout only. I have tested the code and it works. You probably wasn't loading the Layout object properly.

Comment: Hi Mavios, it is working now, I must did something wrong when I first run it. Thank you so much for helping me out on this, I really appreciated your time and efforts.

Comment: @IStop happy to help. One last thing, you just need to choose my answer as accepted solutions so others might benfit.

Comment: I am having issues.